# No obtengo respuesta de Nightmare.js al ejecutarlo desde el CRON

Tags: javascript, nodejs, crontab, fs

He estado trabajando recientemente en un proceso de automatización con Nightmare.js y linux Cron. Tras la ejecución de Nightmare, el script recoge el valor del resultado y lo añade al fichero local de mi ordenador (ningún error de red detectado).

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var fs = require('fs');
var filePath = `${process.env['HOME']}/Documents/ResultCron.txt`;

Nightmare()
    .goto('http://mywebsite.com/form')
    .type('input[id="email"]', 'XXX@gmail.com')
    .click('#submit-button')
    .wait('.formSubmitted')
    .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.formSubmitted').value)
    .end()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(`The form submitted is:\n${result}`)
      fs.appendFileSync(filePath, `\n${result}: ${new Date()}`);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
      fs.appendFileSync(filePath, `\nERROR: ${error}: ${new Date()}`);
    })
```

Cuando ejecuto esto con `node /home/user/Documents/nightmareForm.js` funciona perfectamente y escribe en el fichero. Pero, cuando se ejecuta desde el cron de linux, no añade nada al fichero.

Esta es la configuración que he añadido al crontab:

sudo crontab -e

Se ejecutará cada día a las 13:00

```
0 13 * * * node /home/user/Documents/nightmareForm.js
```

Si hago `grep nightmareForm.js /var/log/syslog -C 10` puedo ver que se ha ejecutado: `Apr 24 13:00:00 PC CRON[1223]: (root) CMD (node /home/user/Documents/nightmareForm.js)`

Continuando la investigación, el fichero tiene los siguientes derechos: -rwxr-xr-x (Ubuntu 18.10), por lo que es ejecutable y el fichero creado: -rw-rw-rw-

He verificado que el script puede escribir en el fichero pero nunca llega a las partes de then() o catch() de nightmare.

¿Alguna idea de por qué no funciona desde el crontab y sí desde node?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Cron se ha ejecutado... ¿pero realmente el fichero se ha ejecutado? ¿Has probado a poner la ruta completa para el ejecutable `node`? Algo como `/usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: Añade tambien un log de registro a ver que sale: `0 13 * * * /usr/local/bin/node /home/user/Documents/nightmareForm.js >> /home/user/Documents/nightmareForm.log 2>&1`

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano :
He probado con rutas absolutas y no hay problema ya que escribe en una primera linea que puse con un test.

Comment: Cron se ejecuta en un entorno distinto al que tiene un terminal, asegúrate de que la variable HOME tiene un valor. Es posible que al no poder crear el log, todo lo demás falle

Comment: Hola! He añadido los logs como indicaba @Fly pero no muestra absolutamente nada. Nightmare parece estar declarado. Empiezo a sospechar que no este cogiendo bien la Promise y falle por eso... 
`Nightmare {
  _endNow: [Function: bound endInstance],
  state: 'initial',
  running: false,
  ending: false,
  ended: false,
...
`